# No logro mostrar los datos que rescato desde un Pipe en Angular

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript, pipe

Estoy intentando usar un Custom Pipe para transformar un Id de Mongo en un nombre que rescato de una base de datos dentro de una vista en HTML y no he tenido buenos resultados.
[image: Resultado Object Object]

Siempre obtengo el mismo resultado **[Object Object]** pero en la consola si recibo lo que estoy buscando. He intentado usar el tipado y tampoco he obtenido buenos resultados por eso preferí usar **Any** Tal vez sea algo tonto que esté pasando por alto, pero estoy bloqueado.

Este es el código del  Pipe

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Producto } from '../../producto/interfaces/producto.interface';
import { ProductoService } from '../../producto/services/producto.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nombre'
})
export class NombrePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private productoService : ProductoService){}

  transform(id : string ) : any {
    return this.productoService.getProducto(id)
     .pipe(
      map( producto => producto.nombre)
      )
      .subscribe( (producto) => {
       console.log(producto);
      } )
    
  }

}
```

Aquí abajo pongo el código de la vista:

```
    <div class="contenedor-venta">
      <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
        <li  *ngFor="let item of productoItem" 
              class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
          <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
            <div class="fw-bold">{{ item.id | nombre }}</div>
            <!-- Content for list item -->
          </div>
          <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{ item.cantidad }}</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
  
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

codigo del servicio:

```
 getProducto(id : string):Observable<Producto>{
    const url : string = `${this.baseUrl}/productos/`
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('x-token', localStorage.getItem('token')  || '');
    return this.http.get<getProductoResponse>(`${url}/${id}`, { headers })
        .pipe(
          map( resp => resp.producto )
        )
  }
```

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda acepto cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Hola hilde652, me he dado cuenta que el       (productoItem) no lo veo en el código que adjuntas.  y no veo en donde asignas el resultado de lo que te trae el servicio.  tal vez es solo eso: y no sé como lo tienes declarado tu variable productoItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te suscribas en el pipe, solo retorna el observable:

```
  transform(id : string ) : any {
        return this.productoService.getProducto(id)
         .pipe(
          map( producto => producto.nombre)
          )
      }
```

Como el pipe `nombre` retorna un observable hay que usar el pipe `async` que se encarga de suscribirse al observable:

```
 <div class="fw-bold">{{ item.id | nombre | async }}</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó. 